# How to check if rufus-scheduler is already running for my Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, rufus-scheduler

I have a Rails application that uses rufus-scheduler to schedule some of its tasks. The scheduler get initialised in the after_fork of a unicorn script initiating the Rails application (Reference: https://gist.github.com/jkraemer/3851917).

Recently, I encountered a scenario where the unicorn scheduler thread got killed while the unicorn process hosting it was still active. This lead to the scheduler being down for a considerable time without notice.

I would like to setup an alert and monitoring system to handle such scenarios that should be capable of:
1. Throwing an alert whenever the scheduler thread is killed/aborted.
2. Restart the scheduler if the Rails process is running.

What would be a suitable way to know the running status of the scheduler, through perhaps a cron task and handle the auto-restart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bring in a cron task to watch rufus-scheduler, why don't you simply drop rufus-scheduler and use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for all the scheduling? You'll thus have a 100% crond solution.

Another alternative, use [Foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) to manage a) your Rails application b) a separate process hosting your rufus-scheduler schedules (it could be a "schedule only" version of your Rails application) (here is a nice example in a [blog post](https://mauricio.github.io/2014/02/09/foreman-and-environment-variables.html)). There is also [God](https://github.com/mojombo/god).

If you look at Clockwork, a gem that was inspired by rufus-scheduler, they [detail](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork#in-production) such one application / multiple processes scenarii.

Then you could look at the various tools out there to watch your logs and alert you in case of error.

**Update:**

Maybe this gist could help: https://gist.github.com/jmettraux/5f716c8568f6ab7bb016a4bc11528bc2

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed list of suggestions. Shall try them out. Couldn't use a 100% cron scheduling since I needed to schedule certain tasks below the 1 minute frequency.

Comment: For monitoring via God script, how can I access the scheduler instance from outside the application ?

Comment: You'll have to implement that access by yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the gist. Huge help.